# Can someone help me figure out what 考えを示しましたが is supposed to mean?

Tags: grammar, kanji, syntax, kana

This entry is hard to find on the web. I've only found 2 entries:
1)【that以下】という考えを示す reveal one's idea that
2) 考えを示す to state one's opinion

立花氏は来週にもＮＨＫに出向いて受信契約をする考えを示しましたが、「契約する義務はあるが、支払いは義務ではない」と主張していて、受信料は支払わない考えです。

Mr. Tachibana has been planning to visit NHK next week to make a receiving contract, but claims that he "is obligated to contract, but not payment," and is not willing to pay the reception fee.

I am pretty sure the above translation is correct, but I'd like to know how. Can this sentence also mean, "Mr. Tachibana has revealed his idea to visit NHK next week to make a receiving contract,"? 
But then if both above definitions are supposed to be correct, why does it sound awkward and incorrect to say "Mr. Tachibana stated his opinion to visit NHK next week to make a receiving contract,"? I've never heard anyone say "I will state my opinion to visit _ place!" in all my life.

Answer (score 3):

This is simply because [考え has many meanings](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%80%83%E3%81%88) and is translated into English in various ways. 考えを示す is not really a tricky idiom; it's a set phrase that means "to show one's 考え", where 考え can be an idea, a plan, a suggestion or an opinion depending on the context. In your example, 考え refers to his plan.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I also was suspecting as much, but wanted to see what others had to say. The pro's will say its unprofessional to look up phrases like this so literally, but what other choice does one have if this particular phrase calls for just that!